# C program doesnt work (maybe something wrong with for or if)

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, input

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("print your full name: ");
    char name[50];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
    printf("%s %c", name, toupper(name[0]));
    for(int i = 1; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
        if(name[i] == ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", name[i++]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

This program must print someone's initials, but it doesn't. I really have no idea why. It only prints the first letter.

Comment: In `%[^\n]s`  remove the `s`

Comment: Always Check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: `printf("%c", name[i++]);` prints a space, because you told it to, when there is a space. It then advances `i` again so the loop will miss the first letter of the second name. If you want to print the second name's initial then `name[i++]` should be  `name[i+1]`

Comment: I don't understand why the question was closed because it needs debugging details and a [mre]. It already provides that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use post-increment of `i` so it results in a space being printed. Instead, use pre-increment to print the character *after* the space.

Example:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("print your full name: ");
    char name[50];
    if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) == NULL) return 1;
//      ^^^^^ scanf replacement
    printf("%s %c", name, toupper((unsigned char)name[0]));
    
    for (size_t i = 1, len = strlen(name); i < len; i++) {
        if (name[i] == ' ' && i + 1 < len) {
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ bounds check
            putchar(toupper((unsigned char)name[++i]));
//                                              ^^^ pre-increment
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The question is badly written, but you answered it. I would never have thought of what the problem was.